# How to hide taskbar icon of window SDL C

Tags: c, sdl

I'm trying to avoid showing a taskbar icon for an SDL window. So far, I'm using SDL_CreateWindow to create the window.

I'm using Windows and the C programming language.

Comment: Try adding `SDL_WINDOW_SKIP_TASKBAR` to `SDL_CreateWindow` flags.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice this flag.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Even though @HolyBackCat has already commented it, I feel that it's missing things. All the list of flags in SDL are here: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowFlags. SDL has brilliant documentation. If you want to check if a feature is present, just go there.

As stated in the link, there's this flag:

> SDL_WINDOW_SKIP_TASKBAR: window should not be added to the taskbar (X11 only, >= SDL 2.0.5)

So, add it to the `flags` parameter in `SDL_CreateWindow`. But, as you can see, it only works with X11 and version 2.0.5 or more. So, beware of it's limitations. I posted this answer just to tell about its limitations. It won't work without X11.

And also, this link is useful: https://wiki.libsdl.org/APIByCategory.

Comment: The documentation seems to be lying. I tried it, and it works on Windows.